# Getting image source when I click Image View

Tags: java, android

This is My Class Code. I can get the image when I can click the Image view and the source transfer to another activity.

How can I get the source of image when I click the image view?

```
imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        String id = String.valueOf(view.getId());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), id, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
});
```

Comment: Can you please explain what did you expect?

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: When i can click the image view how can get the source of image we can click. this is my question actually @EnsarBayhan

Comment: you can't get a source of the imageView. If you set it with the code, then save it somewhere in some variable. If you set it through XML, then create a static map where keys are IDs of ImageViews and values are IDs of the resources they show.

Comment: What do you really mean when you say source of image?

Comment: Sir, Actually i am working in dynamically so how can handle the source ??

Comment: What do you want to send to another activity exactly? how will it be used there?

Comment: I want the source of image we can click the Image View simple.

Comment: @HamzaAlam did you use glide or something?

Comment: the imageview you clicked is in the listview with adapter?

Comment: when you say source, do you mean "R.id.example_name" or the integer value behind it?

Comment: Sir i am using a hard code value we can assign the image view but when i can click the Image View i wish to get the hard code source ..